# SQL How to Select results to show 23:00 instead of 23

Tags: sql, time, hour

beginner question here... I have read documentation and searched the internet for several hours but cannot find the answer. Standard SQL

I am pulling from a table that shows 'hour'

```
select hour as hour
```

the output is

```
1
2
3
```

I would like to to output

```
1:00
2:00
3:00
```

How do I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: To be able to get the correct answer, please edit your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: What's the column type of the column "hour"?

Comment: What specific database are you using?

Comment: I believe BigQuery Standard SQL. The column is returning an INT64

Answer (score 1):

With the information we have there's not much we can say.

See if this works for you.

```
SELECT CAST(hour AS VARCHAR) + ':00' AS [Hour]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: CONCAT(cast(hour as STRING),':00') - worked! thank you so much!

Comment: It would be good if you could add an answer and accept it. Since you've found a solution it makes sense for the question not to remain open.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a string.  In standard SQL:

```
select (hour || ':00')
```

Most databases support `||`, but some have other mechanisms for string concatenation, such as `+` or `concat()`.

Comment: It is returning as an INT64 - how do I concat this with a string? Thank you!

Comment: `||` returns a string and should be converting an integer to a string.

Comment: CONCAT(cast(hour as STRING),':00') - worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: CONCAT(cast(hour as STRING),':00') as hour,